# Decode JSON result stdClass Object() to a formatted HTML

Tags: php, html, json, stdclass

how does one decode a JSON to an html list, and be able to dumb it into a 'div' or DOM element, or am I missing something?

```
stdClass Object ( 
[msc] => 26771010150 
[number] => 2677410930 
[status] => OK 
[msc_mcc] => 652 
[imsi] => 652010151221139 
[mcc] => 652 
[operator_country] => Botswana 
[msc_operator_name] => Mascom Wireless (Pty) Ltd. 
[msc_operator_country] => Botswana 
[msc_mnc] => 01 [mnc] => 01 
[id] => 928692391 
[msc_location] => 
[operator_name] => Mascom Wireless (Pty) Ltd. 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wherever your are decoding json in php, instead of that Use

```
json_decode($json,true)
```

It will return associative array that you can use in html easily.